# Player Detection System Unity is not very accurate

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have written code for player detection system.
I have a boss that will keep looking for the player position and once the player is within a certain sphere collider trigger radius then the player will be detected.
It is done using a raycast and OnTriggerStay and OnTriggerExit.

The problem is that the Player Detection System is not very accurate so sometimes it work , some other times it doesn't. I can't seem to find or understand why.

Here is the part of the code (of interest) I wrote:

```
 void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "player")
    {

        playerDetected = false;

        Vector3 direction = other.transform.position - transform.position;
        float angle = Vector3.Angle(direction, transform.forward);

        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position + transform.up / 2, direction, Color.green);

        if (angle < fieldOfView)
        {

            RaycastHit hit;

            //if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + transform.up / 2, direction, out hit, col.radius, ignoreRaycast))

            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + transform.up / 2, direction,out hit, col.radius))
            {
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "player")
                {
                    playerDetected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "player")
    {
        playerDetected = false;

    }
}
```

and this is the full code:
https://pastebin.com/YZH9Fc99

This will show you the behavior (look at the bool tick of PlayerDetected going on and off)
https://gyazo.com/74961847eca520a335d18c194201d0c2

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that the player was holding a sword with a box collider trigger.
When she moves the sword is above the body collider and it couldn't detect it.
It was solved by adding a layer to the player and to ignore everything but the player layer.

add

```
public LayerMask ignoreRaycast;
```

Replace

```
 if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + transform.up / 2, direction,out hit, col.radius))
```

by

```
 if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + transform.up / 2, direction,out hit, col.radius,ignoreRaycast))
```

For ignoreRaycast select just player layer